# Click Node Without Clicking Parent Node

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<button>` that is wrapped inside of a `<div>`.  I want to be able to click the button without actually clicking on the `<div>` as well.  The `<button>` needs to remain inside of the `<div>`.

Heres the code:

```
<div onclick='console.log("Div was clicked.")'>
    This is the Div
    <button onclick='console.log("Button was clicked.")'>Button</button>
</div>
```

When i click on the `<div>` console logs "Div was clicked.".
When i click on the `<button>` console logs "Button was clicked." AND "Div was clicked.".

How can i click on the `<button>` WITHOUT a click registering on the `<div>`?
Any alternatives/workarounds?

Thanks guys.

Comment: add this to your event handler [event.stopPropagation();] this will prevent bubbling the event to DOM ancestors

Comment: Thanks buddhi, works 100%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `event.stopPropagation()` in your button `onclick` handler.

```
<div onclick='console.log("Div was clicked.")'>
    This is the Div
    <button onclick='event.stopPropagation(); console.log("Button was clicked.")'>Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the `target.id`. Here's a small example using jQuery:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    This is the Div
    <button onclick='console.log("Button was clicked.")'>Button</button>
</div>
```

**[jQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERoHj.png):**

```
$('#parent').click(function(e)
{
    if (e.target.id == "parent") {console.log("Div was clicked.")}
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mrnLLvac/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following JavaScript function:

```
function CancelMouseEvent (Event)
{
   Event = Event ? Event : window.Event;
   if (Event.stopPropagation) { Event.stopPropagation(); }
   if (Event.preventDefault) { Event.preventDefault(); }
   Event.cancelBubble = true;
   Event.cancel = true;
   Event.returnValue = false;
   return false;
}
```

Now use this in HTML:

```
<button onclick='console.log("Button was clicked."); CancelMouseEvent(event);'>Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is recommended to not use the older method of event binding to HTML. It is recommended to use addEventListener, that way your JS stays in your JS and your HTML is only HTML.

A simple example below:

```
<div id="wrap">
    This is the Div
    <button id="button">Button</button>
</div>

<script>
    var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');

    wrap.addEventListener('click', handleClick, true);

    function handleClick(e) {
        e.stopPropagation;

        if (e.target.id === 'button') {
            // do stuff because button was clicked
            console.log('button was clicked');
        }
    }

</script>
```

EDIT: why your code didnt work
Your code didn't work because events "bubble" up the DOM (they can also be "captured"...), in your case even if you clicked "button", the following events were triggered:

Button (target) === (bubbling up to its parent) === DIV (its event was also triggered).